# Table not found in JPA with MySQL database

Tags: mysql, jpa

I try to create a sample project with JPA, EJB and REST service. Service is working well and I can send `Post` and `GET` requests. When I tried to connect insert simple object through EJB, I got table not found error. I tried creating the table manually but it didn't work tr

Here is my Entity class

**Employee**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private int empId;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 63)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, length = 255)
    private String email;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "salary", columnDefinition = "integer default 2500")
    private int salary;

}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="EmployeePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <class>com.ams.company.Entity.Employee</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/company" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />

            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode"
                value="database" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation-mode" value="ddl_database_generation" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**EmployeeManager**

```
@Stateless
public class EmployeeManager {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "EmployeePU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EmployeeManager() {
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
    public boolean addEmployee(Employee employee) {
        entityManager.persist(employee);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question mysql, but you're using the JDBC driver for Apache Derby. Please tag your question accurately, because it'll attract the attention of people who can answer it the best.

Comment: Of course it could explain why you can't connect to MySQL if you're using the wrong JDBC driver.

Comment: Please post the stacktrace of your error message in your question. Are you sure that your application picked up the jdbc connection successfully?

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you, that was the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on comments above:

When connecting to the MySQL Server, you must use the [MySQL JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/).

You can't use the JDBC driver for any other brand of database (the problem in this case was using the Apache Derby JDBC driver).